# Update columns based on multiple complex conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

For the `DataFrame df` below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Tesla','Model3', '-', 'Tesla'),
                  ('Tesla', 'ModelS', '-', 'Tesla_MD3'),
                  ('Tesla', 'ModelX', '-', 'Tesla_MD3'),
                  ('Tesla', 'ModelY', '-', 'Tesla'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Wrangler','Grouped','Jeep'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Compass', 'Grouped','Jeep_MD3'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Patriot', 'Grouped','Jeep'),
                  ('Jeep',  'Cherokee','Grouped','Jeep'),
                  ('Ford',  'Mustang', 'Grouped','Ford'),
                  ('Ford',  'F150',     'Grouped','Ford')  ],columns=['Make','Model','Status','Type'])


df
     Make    Model        Status    Type
0   Tesla   Model3             -    Tesla
1   Tesla   ModelS             -    Tesla_MD3
2   Tesla   ModelX             -    Tesla_MD3
3   Tesla   ModelY             -    Tesla
4   Jeep    Wrangler     Grouped    Jeep
5   Jeep    Compass      Grouped    Jeep_MD3
6   Jeep    Patriot      Grouped    Jeep
7   Jeep    Cherokee     Grouped    Jeep
8   Ford    Mustang      Grouped    Ford
9   Ford    F150         Grouped    Engine
```

I am trying to update the column `Type` with `Make_MD3` for all same `Make`, if `Make_MD3` is present in any of the `Models` in that `Make`, and if the `Status` is `Grouped` for that `Make`. But if the `Status` is not `Grouped`, `Type` should be kept as such for each `Models`. If 'Make_MD3' is not present the `Type` should be maintained as `Make`.

For instance, `Tesla` is not `Grouped`, so each model keeps their `Type` the same. But `Jeep` is `Grouped`, and `Compass` is having its `Type` as `Jeep_MD3`, so `Jeep_MD3` is updated as the `Type` for all `Jeep` `Models`. `Ford` is `Grouped` but none of the `Models` have type `Ford_MD3` so `Type` is kept as `Ford`

Expected output

```
     Make    Model    Status       Type
0   Tesla   Model3      -           Tesla  #For Tesla Type is maintained for each model seperately since it is not grouped
1   Tesla   ModelS      -         Tesla_MD3
2   Tesla   ModelX      -         Tesla_MD3
3   Tesla   ModelY      -            Tesla
4   Jeep    Wrangler   Grouped     Jeep_MD3 #Since Jeep is grouped, all its Type is changed to Jeep_MD3 since one of the model had Jeep_MD3
5   Jeep    Compass    Grouped     Jeep_MD3
6   Jeep    Patriot    Grouped     Jeep_MD3
7   Jeep    Cherokee   Grouped     Jeep_MD3
8   Ford    Mustang    Grouped        Ford #Even though Ford is grouped, since there is no Ford_MD3 the Type is maintained as Ford.
9   Ford    F150       Grouped        Ford
```

In other words,
The conditions are for all the `makes`(eg. Jeeps) If the `make` is grouped and if `MD3` is appended to any of the model `types`, then all the grouped models in the same `make` will have the MD3 appended to them.
I tried the below code but it doesn't work. Can someone fix that approach or try a new approach?

```
df.loc[df.Status.eq('Grouped'), 'Type'] = df[df.Status.eq('Grouped')].groupby('Make').Type.transform(
    lambda x: f"{x.str.replace('_MD3','')}_{MD3}" if x.str.contains('_MD3').any() else x)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df.loc[df.Status == "Grouped", "Type"] = (
    df[df.Status == "Grouped"]
    .groupby("Make")["Type"]
    .transform(
        lambda x: x.name + "_MD3" if x.str.endswith("_MD3").any() else x.name
    )
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Make     Model   Status       Type
0  Tesla    Model3        -      Tesla
1  Tesla    ModelS        -  Tesla_MD3
2  Tesla    ModelX        -  Tesla_MD3
3  Tesla    ModelY        -      Tesla
4   Jeep  Wrangler  Grouped   Jeep_MD3
5   Jeep   Compass  Grouped   Jeep_MD3
6   Jeep   Patriot  Grouped   Jeep_MD3
7   Jeep  Cherokee  Grouped   Jeep_MD3
8   Ford   Mustang  Grouped       Ford
9   Ford      F150  Grouped       Ford
```